# What are the parameter of the Image() in tcpdf?

Tags: php, tcpdf

I need to align an image . But I did not get with the parameters passed inside the Image function in tcpdf .

`$pdf->Image(Image_Path, 0, 250, 210 , 0, 'PNG', '', '', false, 300, '', false, false, 0, 'LB', false, false);`

Answer (score 16):

Image( `filename`, `left`, `top`, `width`, `height`, `type`, `link`, `align`, `resize`, `dpi`, `align`, `ismask`, `imgmask`, `border`, `fitbox`, `hidden`, `fitonpage`)

**filename** : name of the file containing the image
**left** : from left
**top**: from top
**width**: width of the image. Zero for automatically calculated
**height** : height of the image. Zero for automatically calculated.
**type**: JPG, JPEG, PNG. If not specified, the type is inferred from the file extension.
**link**:URL or identifier returned by AddLink()
**align**: T (top), M (middle), B (bottom), N (next line)
**resize**: true/false. If true resize (reduce) the image to fit :w and :h (requires RMagick library); if false do not resize; if 2 force resize in all cases (upscaling and downscaling).
**dpi**: dot-per-inch resolution used on resize. Recommended 300
**align**: align L (left), C (center), R (right)
**ismask**: true if this image is a mask, false otherwise 
**imgmask**: image object returned by this function or false.
**border**:
0: no border (default)
1: frame
or a string containing some or all of the following characters (in any order):
L: left
T: top
R: right
B: bottom

**fitbox**: If true scale image dimensions proportionally to fit within the (:w, :h) box.
**hidden**: true/false
**fitonpage**: if true the image is resized to not exceed page dimensions.

From https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rfpdf/1.17.1/TCPDF:Image

Answer (score 4):

The [documentation](https://tcpdf.org/docs/srcdoc/tcpdf/class-TCPDF/#_Image) is a good start:

> Image( $file, $x = '', $y = '', $w = 0, $h = 0, $type = '', $link = '', $align = '', $resize = false, $dpi = 300, $palign = '', $ismask = false, $imgmask = false, $border = 0, $fitbox = false, $hidden = false, $fitonpage = false, $alt = false, $altimgs = array() )

What do you mean by "align"?

Comment: Where can I find the meaning for $ismask, $imgmask, $alt etc?

Comment: Unfortunatelly, this documentation is somehow crippled, but the source code has doxygen comments, which list also description of the arguments. For example here is the documentation for the Image() arguments:
https://github.com/tecnickcom/TCPDF/blob/master/tcpdf.php#L6790

Answer (score 2):

```
Image( $file, $x = '', $y = '', $w = 0, $h = 0, $type = '', $link = '', $align = '', $resize = false, $dpi = 300, $palign = 'C', $ismask = false, $imgmask = false, $border = 0, $fitbox = false, $hidden = false, $fitonpage = false, $alt = false, $altimgs = array() )
```

Put C for center align, L for Left align, R for right align

Answer (score 0):

```
$tcpdf->Image('../xyz.png', $x=150, $y=10, $w=40, $h=20, 'PNG');
```

Comment: Please explain your answer to make it better.